# Compare Area of two matrices Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Let, `cv::Mat matrix_1` and `cv:Mat matrix_2` be two matrices. How can we compare these two matrices?

- `matrix_1 < matrix_2`
- `matrix_1 >= matrix_2`

I used the following approach:

```
 if((matrix_1.rows < matrix_2.rows) && (matrix_1.cols < matrix_2.cols)) then matrix_1 < matrix_2
```

---

**Reason for asking the question**

I am using a query image in order to find the closest match in a database. and I want the size of the query Image which is matrix_1 to be less than the size of all the other images in the database.

**Link:** [Tutorial matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html)

Comment: The method will depend on the result you want. There are infinite number of comparsion variants.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Well I Want the query matrix `matrix_1` to be less than `matrix_2`. Meaning I want to check if  `row x col` of matrix_1 to be less than `row x col` of matrix_2

Comment: do you only want to compare their size/area ? (not looking at their content ?)

Comment: @berak yes just Area. Not not the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, if you only want to compare the area:

```
Mat A = ...
Mat B = ...

int areaA = (A.rows*A.cols);
int areaB = (B.rows*B.cols);

bool a_is_smaller = areaA < areaB;
```

Comment: Also a question should the size of the query image be less than the size of the images in the database? When we are working with opencv?

Comment: ^^ sorry, i did not understand that. "size of the query image" ? query for what ? template matching ?

Comment: yes, that should be smaller. but also consider using a ROI of the part you're specifically interested in.